# javascript setInterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
function noti() {
     document.title = document.title + " 1"
}

setInterval("noti()", 1000)
```

The problem is it outputs:

> My title 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 .....  to infinite.... 1

Is there any possible way to output this as "My title 1"

the **noti()** function serves as a purpose when everytime an update occurs in the database, *whatever is the length gathered from the database* it will be outputed into the users **title bar**.

> So, "My title 1", where "My title" is the name of the user and "1" the length coming from the database

Comment: Why are you using `setInterval`?

Comment: It's mention there >the noti() function serves as a purpose when everytime an update occurs in the database, whatever is the length gathered from the database it will be outputed into the users title bar.

I used setInterval 'coz I need to get the update every second

Comment: Instead of passing a string to `setInterval` or `setTimeout`, pass a function "reference": http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#other.timeouts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically something like this is tagged. Usually you'll see something like `(1) My title`.

In this case it's a simple matter:

```
function noti(num) { // num is the number of notifications
    document.title = document.title.replace(/^(?:\(\d+\) )?/,"("+num+") ");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to execute `noti` only once, you should be using [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout), not `setInterval`.

**Update:** OK, so you want to execute `noti` continuously but replace the suffix instead of adding it anew each time. Do this with a regular expression replace:

```
document.title = document.title.replace(/(\b\s*\d+)?$/, " " + num);
```

[**See it in action**](http://jsfiddle.net/XgSwW/).

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
var ttl = document.title; //initalize title
function noti() {
  document.title = ttl + " 1";
  //if you want to continue setting the title 
  //(so periodically repeat setting document.title) 
  //uncomment the following:
  //setTimeout(noti, 1000);
}

//use a function reference here. 'noti()' will
//cause the interpreter to do an eval
setTimeout(noti, 1000);
```

See [why you shouldn't use `setInterval`](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2009/05/14/setinterval-is-moderately-evil.aspx)